# Managing personal projects

Tags: version-control, project-management, infrastructure

I want to introduce Jira and Perforce for my personal projects at home. The question I have is about infrastructure. How do you setup your personal production environment? Do you have an own server at home that hosts source control and project management, do you use a rented server or does this all run on your (main) development machine?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. :)

Regards,
Alex

Comment: You have Jira and Perforce licenses at home? Wow. Generally Trac & SVN would be the more common configuration.

Comment: Jira only costs 10 US$ if you don't need it for more than 10 users. The Perforce server is free for two users and since I develop on my own that's enough. The decision for this software is just my personal preference.
My question is more about how and where do you setup such tools for your personal work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends... 
... If you want to keep your projects private and possibly do some freelancing, I would strongly recommend a paid hosted solution, like projectlocker.com, or similar one, including at least version control + issue tracker + wiki. You will focus o your work, released of backup and maintenance tasks.

... If you don't care to manage your on server and do the backups, then I would recommend Jira $10 + GIT or Subversion.

... If you plan to share it or make it opensource, look for something like github.com

While perforce is great, svn/git are more than OK, free, and widely supported.